# comparing float and double and printing them

Tags: double

I have a quick question.  So, say I have a really big number up to like 15 digits, and I would take the input and assign it to two variables, one float and one double if I were to compare two numbers, how would you compare them?  I think double has the precision up to like 15 digits?  and float has 8?  So, do I simply compare them while the float only contains 8 digits and pad the rest or do I have the float to print out all 15 digits and then make the comparison?  Also, if I were asked to print out the float number, is the standard way of doing it is just printing it up to 8 digits? which is its max precision

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most languages will do some form of type promotion to let you compare types that are not identical, but reasonably similar. For details, you would have to indicate what language you are referring to.

Of course, the real problem with comparing floating point numbers is that the results might be unexpected due to rounding errors. Most mathematical equivalences don't hold for floating point artihmetic, so two sequences of operations which SHOULD yield the same value might actually yield slightly different values (or even very different values if you aren't careful).

EDIT: as for printing, the "standard way" is based on what you need. If, for some reason, you are doing monetary computations in floating point, chances are that you'll only want to print 2 decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in terms of digits may be a problem here. Floats can have a range from negative infinity to positive infinity. In C# for example the range is ±1.5 × 10^−45 to ±3.4 × 10^38 with a precision of 7 digits.

Also, IEEE 754 defines floats and doubles. 
Here is a link that might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score -1):

Your question is the right one.  You want to consider your approach, though.

Whether at 32 or 64 bits, the floating-point representation is not meant to compare numbers for equality.  For example, the assertion `2.0/7.0 == 60.0/210.0` may or may not be true in the CPU's view.  Conceptually, the floating-point is inherently meant to be imprecise.

If you wish to compare numbers for equality, use integers.  Consider again the ratios of the last paragraph.  The assertion that `2*210 == 7*60` is always true -- noting that those are the integral versions of the same four numbers as before, only related using multiplication rather than division.  One suspects that what you are really looking for is something like this.